# In RethinkDB using multi indexes for tags, how to get items that match more than one tag?

Tags: tagging, rethinkdb

Suppose I have a story table (with example data):

```
 story
 {id: 1, name: 'First Story', tags: ['plants', 'flowers', 'dog']}
 {id: 2, name: 'Second Story', tags: ['flowers', 'wedding']}
 {id: 3, name: 'Third Story', tags: ['plants', 'wedding']}
```

The story table has a multi index on the `tags` field.

I can get all stories that have the `plants` tag with:

```
 r.table('story').getAll('plants', {index: tags})
```

Now how would I get all stories that have **both** the `plants` and `wedding` tags in an effecient manner (hopefully utilizing the tags multi index)?

The use case requires user selectable filtering on an arbitrary number of arbitrary tags.

Answer (score 3):

Passing multiple arguments to `getAll` finds the documents that match either tag:

```
r.table('story').getAll('plants', 'wedding', {index: 'tags'})
```

A simple multi-index on tags cannot be used to match all tags. A query that doesn't use an index would look like:

```
r.table('story').filter(r.row('tags').contains('plants','wedding'))
```

It might be possible to create and use a multi-index on the powerset of tags:

```
r.table('story').indexCreate('tags-powerset', r.row('tags').do(powerset), {multi:true})
r.table('story').getAll(['plants', 'wedding'], {index: 'tags'})
```

Because of restrictions of ReQL and in the interest of efficiency, the powerset function may need to be approximated, for example as:

```
function(tags) {
  return tags.concatMap(function(a){
    tags.map(function(b){
      return [a,b] })})}
```

Comment: In the 'tags-powerset' example, I'm guessing the getAll should use the 'tags-powerset' index?